# A message to a Puzzling User

Tags: wordplay, crossword-clues

I have decided to send a message to a fellow Puzzling User.
Solve the following clues to find out the message:

> An intense request for a bargain (4)
>
> Shorten this great community without including its leader.(2)
>
> short commercial in the Internet, domain(3 or 4)
>
> Most common in this language(1)
>
> Give support to the rear end. (4)
>
> Your chances are 50-50. If only, 5 was a letter once.. (2)
>
> Open this not while having tea. (2)
>
> It is a wreck. If only, it was invented 4 years later without its tail.(4)
>
> Travel through that and criticise it (4)

After you have figured out the message, Don't you all agree with me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message appears to say

> PLEA/SE/COM/E/BACK/SO/ON/AVIG/RAIL

all of which is pretty straightforward with the following exceptions:

> SO is because SO looks like 50
>  AVIG is still eluding me.

EDIT: Lukas Rotter (in Sphinx's Room chat) worked out that

> AVIG is rot4(WREC).

More details, in case anyone wants them:

> `PLEA`: an intense request; in US criminal context, a "plea bargain" is what you do when the prosecutors tell you you're liable to go down for 50 years unless you agree to plead guilty to some of the charges.
>  `SE`: PSE (short for puzzling.stackexchange.com) minus its first letter.
>  `COM`: internet domain name (.com), short for "commercial"
>  `E`: commonest letter in English
>  `BACK`: means both "give support to" and "rear end"
>  `SO`: looks like 50 as in "50-50" but with 5 replaced by a similar-looking letter
>  `ON`: I confess I'm not sure exactly how this works, but something like this: it means the same as "open" in some contexts (e.g., referring to an event) and is (an anagram) of "not" without its final T ("tea"). I suspect I may be failing to understand this clue.  (OP'S edit: Open means "On" in some events. Take the first letter of the first 3 words and remove "t" (Tea))
>  `AVIG`: take WRECK, remove its last letter ("tail"), advance each letter four places; you get AVIG (OP'S edit- Hence, the 4 years later thing)
>  `RAIL`: means both "travel through" (by train) and "criticise".

And I think it's fair to guess that we do pretty much all agree.

Comment: I have a feeling it should be 'please come back to us avigrail'

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Sid confirmed in the Sphinx's Lair that *"SO"* is correct, and "ON" also makes perfect sense with the corresponding clue.

Comment: I don't know about "perfect sense"; at least, I don't understand exactly how it works. I am probably just being dim.

Comment: @LukasRotter Please elaborate re "ON"? I don't get it.

Comment: @randal'thor Then it's just me who has a dumb theory for it: "*Open this **not** while having tea*" - You take the letter "t" (tea) from "not", and then "open" it (like a knot)... I'm a noob in cryptic clues, and just read now that every clue has to include a definition half, so I'm not sure where that is.

Comment: Yeah, ON is a bit of a stretch... @GarethMcCaughan Mind if I edit it in?

Comment: Please feel free.

Comment: I'm pretty sure where you say PSE is `programming.stackexchange.com` you meant to say puzzling

Comment: D'oh, of course I did. Will fix.

Comment: (Done. There isn't even a programming.stackexchange.com!)

Answer (score 4):

*An intense request for a bargain (4)*

> **PLEA** - definitely an "intense request". Not sure how this fits with "bargain", but it fits together so well with the next clue ...

*Shorten this great community without including its leader.(2)*

> PSE without its "leader" is **SE**.

*short commercial in the Internet, domain(3 or 4)*

> **COM**: internet domains often end with .com, this being a short version of "commercial".

*Most common in this language(1)*

> **E**, the commonest letter in English.

*Give support to the rear end. (4)*

> Not sure yet ...

*Your chances are 50-50. If only, 5 was a letter once.. (2)*

> Perhaps this is **SO**, 50-50 turned into letters but each letter appearing only once?

*Open this not while having tea. (2)*

> If this is a wordplay clue, perhaps it's something like **HI** got by removing the T ("tea") from "this"? But I can't see how one of the remaining three letters would be removed to give a clue of length 2.

*It is a wreck. If only, it was invented 4 years later without its tail.(4)*

> Perhaps **WREC** - the word "wreck" without its "tail" or final letter? Not sure about the "4 years" bit though.

*Travel through that and criticise it (4)*

> Not sure yet ...

**Final answer**

> PLEASE COME *[...]*

Comment: So it says so far 'Please come ???? oo hi wrec ????'. Start has to be right

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yeah, it's pretty clear that not *all* of "oo", "hi", and "wreck" are right. One of them might be though.

Comment: First bits are correct, you still have a few stuff to figure out.. :-)

Comment: @Sid Just made another edit ... aaah, never mind, I see Gareth has got it.